# In Azure API Management, is it possible to have a template parameter that allows slashes (e.g., a path)?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-lake, azure-api-management

I'm using Azure Data Lake Storage to store a large amount of files. I'm setting up an Azure API Management gateway in front of it, which rewrites the URI and sets the backend service to the [ADLS REST API (Gen2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2).

At this point I'm trying to configure the **[Path - Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/read)** pass-through. My operation in APIM is `/data/{filesystem}/{path}?timeout={timeout}`, which I would like to be able to call as follows:

(`timeout` is optional)

```
filesystem: MyFileSystem
path:       Path/To/File.json
```

```
GET https://example.com/api/data/MyFileSystem/Path/To/File.json
```

However, when I navigate to this operation in the Azure Portal and use the **Test** feature, it reports the following error:

> `{ "message": "Unable to identify Api or Operation for this request. Responding to the caller with 404 Resource Not Found." }`

I understand that APIM is likely looking for an operation matching `/MyFileSystem/Path/To/File.json` and cannot find one.

For what it's worth, my **[Path - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list)** endpoint works as I'd expect, which is why I know it's specifically the `{path}` that's holding me up.

```
GET https://example.com/api/data/MyFileSystem?recursive=true&resource=filesystem
```

> `200 OK`

I imagine I can change from a template parameter to a query parameter, but I'd prefer to avoid that route for now. So, is there a way to have a template parameter that allows slashes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Last template parameter may have slashes. Use {*path}.

Comment: Not completely necessary, but is there documentation available for this?

Comment: Not for this I'm afraid

Comment: Doesn't fully work. What it does for me: it passes it to a query string parameter and assumes the API supports that. Will not work for Azure Functions unless you build your Function to support that. @VitaliyKurokhtin will this be changed any time?

Comment: I'd suggest starting new thread and posting more details about your problem

Comment: This works. Not directly in Apim, but tried it using `curl`

Comment: saved my agony of several hours with this tiny hack...

Answer (score 1):

You are right Santi, slashes in template param will make APIM unable to find corresponding operation to handle requests.What's more, it is useless that you URL-encode the slashes as APIM will URL-encode your param again if it includes special characters which will mass the path. 
I tested your scenario on Azure storage, if your use "\" to replace "/" it works well , you can have a try on it :

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the input and clarification. Luckily for me, it turns out you can include slashes if you wildcard the param: `{*path}` instead of `{path}`.

Comment: To clarify. {path} will not capture slashes. {*path} can be used as last parameter in URL template and will capture rest of path, including slashes. And there is a bug at the moment in test control in Azure Portal that treats wildcard parameters as query, will be fixed.